# How to uninstall EGit

Tags: eclipse, egit

How can I uninstall EGit?

I cannot find the feature in the Marketplace,

[image: marketplace]

It is not listed as installed,

[image]

It does not show up if I search for it,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Yet it is still there:

[image]

My installation:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the bug link? I am seeing this issue in Build id: 20180917-1800. I just want to remove it because I strongly believe it's messing with my devstyles plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems to be a problem of the ***Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers*** package that **EGit is not uninstallable**. Please report it to Eclipse by opening a bug.

For all other packages (at least for the Java package) EGit can be uninstalled by doing the following:

1. ***Help  > About Eclipse***
2. Click the ***Installation Details*** button
3. In the *Installed Software* tab, filter for `egit`
4. **Select** all items and click ***Uninstall...*** (if *Uninstall...* is not shown, try to run Eclipse as admin/root)

[image]

Comment: It does not show up in that list, see edited question.

Comment: Do you find it somewhere when you expand some items? If it is below _Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers_, you can not uninstall it. In this case, it is a problem of the _Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers_ package and please report it to Eclipse (to the EPP project).

Comment: I added another screenshot.

Comment: I think I found the feature, but uninstall is not available. See screenshot.

Comment: @kerner1000 Sorry, you are right. This seems to be a bug of the _Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers_ package. See my edited answer.

Comment: @kerner1000 Thx for reporting it to Eclipse. As workaround, you can get the _Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers_ package and install the _Remote Application Platform (RAP)_ (via _Help > Install New Software..._ and the Oxygen update site).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to start with a "clean" Platform. But I think EGit is preinstalled everywhere.

Comment: @kerner1000 Yes, it is preinstalled in all packages (except in _Eclipse for Testers_ which is not for developers). But it should be possible to uninstall EGit/JGit in other packages. If you just want to get rid of the Git icons and menu entries you can use _Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective..._ You can also build your own package by using the [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: @howlger, please do not suggest re-opening bugs. This seems to be a specific issue with one package. It should be covered within a new bug.